# Possible to automate posts to WordPress containing nonstandard fields created by a plugin?

Tags: wordpress, perl

I'm using a Perl script to post to a WordPress site using [`WWW::Mechanize`](http://metacpan.org/module/WWW::Mechanize).

I'm thinking of making the script more robust by using an existing CPAN module like [`WordPress::XMLRPC`](http://metacpan.org/module/WordPress::XMLRPC) for posting content to the site.

Before I dive in, I want to be sure I will be able to add data to fields on the post form that are not generated by WordPress but by a plugin. The plugin I'm using generates a text field on the post form which accepts the URL of an MP3 file. I want to be able to input data into this field using the API.

If it's not possible, I'll just stick with `WWW::Mechanize`.

Answer (score 0):

So using `WordPress::XMLRPC` I did something like this:

```
my $post = { 
  title => 'test',
  mt_allow_comments => 0,
  description => '<p>description here</p>',
  custom_fields => [{key => 'enclosure', value => 'http://example.com/files/156842076.mp3'}],
};

$site->newPost($post, 0);
```